# Testing prototypes for CarPlay

Tags: automotive-ux

What are people using for testing designs for your mobile app that have CarPlay views, prior to getting engineering involved in building actual CarPlay functionality?

The best I can come up with is to embed a [`WKWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) in a base Test Flight build -- but Apple underscores how it should only be used for static content.